# Unable to test payment with paypal using Rest Api using dummy credit Cards

Tags: paypal

I am following the below code project example, "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/870870/Using-Paypal-Rest-API-with-ASP-NET-MVC."
I got success with First approach(payment ithCreditCard) and i got success with second approach too did some transactions.But after some time i tried again, now i am getting error "The card used by you not ....". Please Somebody help in this regard.

Comment: I used the card numbers provided in "http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/"